# C program printing out higher number than expected

Tags: c

I am reading 'The C Programming Language 2nd Edition' and exercise 1.8 tells me to write a program that counts blanks, tabs, and spaces in an input. The current code does everything right except for counting the proper amount of blanks and tabs. Below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount;

    blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if(c == ' ') {
            blankCount++;
        } else if(c == '\t') {
            tabCount++;
        } else if(c == '\n') {
            newlineCount++;
        }
    }

    printf("Number of blanks in input: %d\n", blankCount);
    printf("Number of tabs in input: %d\n", tabCount);
    printf("Number of newlines in input: %d\n", newlineCount);
}
```

With this input

```
this is a test
this    is a tab
```

I get this output

```
Number of blanks in input: 2078001861
Number of tabs in input: 32766
Number of newlines in input: 2
```

The expected output is this

```
Number of blanks in input: 3
Number of tabs in input: 1
Number of newlines in input: 2
```

Why am I getting super high numbers instead of the proper amount?

Comment: We need to see your code. Please edit your post and include it in a code block. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Oh my gosh I'm sorry I forgot haha

Comment: I updated it to include my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have uninitialised variables. The initialisation line:

```
int c, blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount;
```

does not actually initialise them to anything<sup>(a)</sup>, and the assignment line:

```
blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount = 0;
```

will simply *evaluate* the three sub-expressions<sup>(b)</sup> and throw away the results. Only the *third* subcomponent `newlineCount = 0` has the side effect of zeroing that variable.

The others will still have some arbitrary value meaning their final value will not indicate correctly the quantities of each.

What you should have instead is something like:

```
int c, blankCount = 0, tabCount = 0, newlineCount = 0;
```

as the initialisation line of your function, and get rid of the assignment line altogether.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Covered in, for example `C11 6.7.9 Initialization /10`:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> As you get to know C more deeply, you'll realise they *are* expressions. The "statement" `pi = 3.14159` is actually an expression that results in `pi` with the side effect of first setting it to that value. That's why you can do things like `twopi = 2 * (pi = 3.14159)` and why `oldi = i++` works.

It also allows for weirdness like being able to compile the statement:

```
42;
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
int c, blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount;
```

Into:

```
int c, blankCount = 0, tabCount = 0, newlineCount = 0;
```

Your line [that came close]:

```
blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount = 0;
```

Only zeroes out `newLineCount` and *not* the other two (these are three separate statements and the first two are [effectively] no-ops).

They are the equivalent of:

```
blankCount;
tabCount;
newlineCount = 0;
```

If you had compiled with `-Wall`, you'd have gotten warnings:

```
init.c: In function ‘main’:
init.c:6:15: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount = 0;
               ^
init.c:6:25: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount = 0;
                         ^
```

Comment: @JordanBaron - uninitialized variables in function scope have quasi-random values.  There are compiler option (or combinations of options) that will earn you about using uninitialized variables.   If your compiler has them, use them. If not, get a better compiler.

Comment: You don't get random numbers. You get whatever was in that chunk of memory before. It's perfectly deterministic, even if mostly inscrutable.

Comment: @torstenvl: it's actually not *required* to be deterministic, the standard says indeterminate. That means an implementation is free to set it to a random number if it wants to :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is this line:

```
blankCount, tabCount, newlineCount = 0;
```

which you probably think is assigning zero to all variables.
In order to accomplish that, however, you need to do:

```
blankCount = tabCount = newlineCount = 0;
```

If you use commas instead, what essentially is happening is that you are *evaluating* `blankCount`, then `tabCount`, then `newlineCount = 0`, and returning the evaluation result of `newlineCount = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

before define a variable should initialization, if not, the variable will become uncertain，if you using visual studio, you can press F11 to perform step by step.